# Erro de conversão e m classes com a mesma interface

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, cast

Tenho a classe mais genérica Conta e outra `ContaPoupaça` que herda dessa classe `Conta`. Nesta filha eu tenho uma interface chamada `ITributavel`, pois essa classe além dos métodos e atributos de `Conta`, tem um método de `ITributavel`.

Tenho outra classe `TotalDeTributos` que tem um método que faz uma operação com a classe `ContaPoupanca` que tem o `ITributável`. No método `AdicionaConta`, da foto abaixo, coloquei como argumento conta do tipo `Conta` e está dando esse erro, eu já tentei usar *casting* pra converter `novaConta` mas dá outro erro.

Não quero que o argumento tenha conta como do tipo `ContaCorrente`, porque outras classes que herdam de Conta terão o `ITributável` e outra não.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Banco2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int indice1 = 0;
        int indice2 = 0;
        private int indiceNovaConta = 0;
        string tipoConta = "";

        private Conta[] contas = new Conta[10];
        TotalDeTributos tributos;
        ContaPoupanca c1;
        ContaInvestimento c2;
        Conta selecionada;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c1 = new ContaPoupanca();
            c1.Titular = new Cliente("Rodrigo");
            c1.Numero = 1;
            this.AdicionarConta(c1);



            c2 = new ContaInvestimento();
            c2.Titular = new Cliente("Diego");
            c2.Numero = 2;
            this.AdicionarConta(c2);


            tributos = new TotalDeTributos();


            AtualizaTributo();
            lblValor.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btnDeposita_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double valorAcao = Convert.ToDouble(lblValor.Text);

            contas[indice1].Deposita(valorAcao);
            MessageBox.Show("Deposito realizado.");
            txtSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(contas[indice1].Saldo);
            lblValor.Text = "0";
            AtualizaTributo();

        }

        private void btnSaque_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double valorOperacao = Convert.ToDouble(lblValor.Text);

            contas[indice1].Saque(valorOperacao);

            txtSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(contas[indice1].Saldo);
            lblValor.Text = "0";

        }

        private void btnTransferir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double valorOperacao = Convert.ToDouble(lblValor.Text);
            contas[indice1].Transfere(valorOperacao, contas[indice2]);

            txtSaldo2.Text = Convert.ToString(contas[indice2].Saldo);
            txtSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(contas[indice1].Saldo);
            lblValor.Text = "0";

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            indice1 = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            selecionada = this.contas[indice1];

            txtTitular.Text = selecionada.Titular.Nome;
            txtSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(selecionada.Saldo);
            txtNumConta.Text = Convert.ToString(selecionada.Numero);

        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            indice2 = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
            selecionada = this.contas[indice2];

            txtTitular2.Text = selecionada.Titular.Nome;
            txtSaldo2.Text = Convert.ToString(selecionada.Saldo);
            txtNumConta2.Text = Convert.ToString(selecionada.Numero);

        }

        public void AdicionarConta(Conta novaConta)
        {


            if (novaConta is ContaPoupanca)
            {
                this.tipoConta = "Conta Poupança";
            }
            else if (novaConta is ContaCorrente)
            {
                this.tipoConta = "Conta Corrente";
            }

            this.contas[this.indiceNovaConta] = novaConta;
            Conta selecionada = this.contas[this.indiceNovaConta];
            comboBox1.Items.Add(selecionada.Titular.Nome + " - Tipo: " + this.tipoConta);
            comboBox2.Items.Add(selecionada.Titular.Nome + " - Tipo: " + this.tipoConta);

            if(selecionada is ContaPoupanca)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(selecionada.GetType().ToString());
                tributos.Acumula((ITributavel)selecionada);
            }

            indiceNovaConta++;

        }

        private void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormCadastrarConta formCadastrarConta = new FormCadastrarConta(this);
            int indiceUltimaConta = contas.Length;
            formCadastrarConta.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void AtualizaTributo()
        {

            if (tributos != null)
            {
                foreach(Conta conta in contas)
                {
                    if(conta is ContaPoupanca || conta is ContaInvestimento)
                    {
                        tributos.Acumula((ITributavel)conta);
                    }
                }


                txtTributos.Text = Convert.ToString(tributos.Total);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

TotalDeTributos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Banco2
{
    class TotalDeTributos
    {
        public double Total { get; private set; }

        public void Acumula(ITributavel conta)
        {
            this.Total += conta.CalcularTributo();
        }

    }
}
```

ITributavel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Banco2
{
    interface ITributavel
    {
        double CalcularTributo();
    }
}
```

[image: Print do erro]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Try catch ajuda muito

Answer (score 2):

Você não postou a classe `Conta`, mas já dá para saber que ela não implementa `ITributavel`, portanto não tem como usar um objeto do tipo `Conta` em uma parâmetro que espera um `ITributavel`.

Se não pode colocar esta interface em `Conta`, então tem que criar um objeto do tipo `ContaPoupanca` e não `Conta` para passar como argumento. Pode até criar um objeto baseado em `novaConta` se verificar que o objeto é uma `ContaPoupanca`. Se estiver usando C# 7 pode até usar [*pattern matching*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não vem ao caso, mas acho que esta modelagem tem outros problemas conceitais. E tem outros problemas no código, mesmo que não dê erro.

Comment: Estou seguindo uma apostila, mas sempre gosto de implementar algo a mais pra testar o conhecimento adquirido. Lá fala que Conta é a classe mais genérica. Algumas classes que herdam de Conta terão tributos e outras não, por isso estou tentando passar algo do tipo Conta no argumento. É dito na apostila que uso de Interface resolveria esse problema.

E se possível me falar quais error pra eu corrigir. Quero aprender a fazer do jeito certo.

Comment: É muita coisa..

Comment: Eita :/ O que vc recomendar estudar para acertar isso?

Comment: Muita coisa ;) .

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo,

Acho que o conceito de interface que está te atrapalhando.
Veja a interface `ITributavel` como um contrato que deve ser cumprido.
Assim, no seu método acumula, ele espera um objeto que cumpra o contrato.

Para cumprir este contrato você precisa decorar a classe que será instanciada e repassada ao método como objeto com a interface `ITributavel` e cumprir o contrato, ou seja, implementar na classe o método `double CalcularTributo();`.

Seria algo como:

```
public class Conta : ITributavel {

   public double CalcularTributo() {
       // implementar regras de negócio
       return 0;
   }

}
```

Desta forma você está garantindo que o objeto passado tem o método `CalcularTributo()` e assim você conseguirá executar a linha `this.Total += conta.CalcularTributo()` - já que ele não sabe que você passou uma Conta ou ContaPoupanca, mas sabe que o objeto que você passou cumpre o contrato `ITributavel` e assim tem o método esperado.

Não analisei o restante do código, mas acho que o ponto central é o cumprimento deste contrato estabelecido através da interface.